# Negative dollars and iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying to assign a form field in a PDF through iTextSharp that has a negative dollar amount. The value is a simple string that starts with '-$'. Every time I add the value to the form using SetField, anything after the negative sing is lost. Positive dollar amounts are fine, only negative values are lost.

I am adding the value as such:

form.SetField(fieldName, fieldValue);

form is of type AcroFields, fieldName and fieldValue are both strings. I have traced down to the point where the string is being passed to SetFields, and its right there. I have also tried replacing '$' with the Unicode value to no avail. Am I supposed to escape the dollar sign? And if so, does anyone know what the escape character is?

Comment: Do you have any formatting options specified on the field? If so, can you just pass a negative number without the dollar sign?

Comment: No, other than applying a font there are no options. Yes, negative numbers work without the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue though I do not totally understand the cause. The field was defined as a multi-line text box even though it was being used as a single line. I unchecked the option for the box to be multi-line and the issue went away.